# Why file name is not set when uploaded to google drive?

Tags: qt, google-drive-api, qt5

**My Objective**
I want to upload a sqlite file to google drive.

Although I have been able to achieve uploading the file to google drive, the **file uploaded name is being "Untitled"**. I tried [Performing Multipart Upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/multipart-upload) with the help of Qt's [QHttpMultiPart](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qhttpmultipart.html).

Here is my code

```
bool File_Control::Upload_File_Multipart(const QString &FileName, const QByteArray &rawData)
{
    if(FileName.isEmpty()){
        emit setMessage("Error: File Name can not be empty");
        return false;
    }

    if(rawData.size()==0){
        emit setMessage("Error: File size can not be zero");
        return false;
    }

    // Prepare MetaDataPart
    QHttpPart MetadataPart;
    MetadataPart.setRawHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    QString Body;
    Body = "{\n"
            + tr("\"name\": \"%1\"\n").arg(FileName)
            + tr("}");
    MetadataPart.setBody(Body.toUtf8());

    // Prepare MediaPart 
    QHttpPart MediaPart;
    MediaPart.setRawHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
    MediaPart.setBody(rawData);

    // Now add MetaDataPart and MediaPart together to form multiPart
    QHttpMultiPart *multiPart = new QHttpMultiPart(QHttpMultiPart::RelatedType);
    multiPart->setBoundary("bound1"); 
    multiPart->append(MetadataPart);
    multiPart->append(MediaPart);

    // Now Prepare the request
    QUrl url("https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart");
    QNetworkRequest request(url);
    QString AccessTokenBearer = "Bearer " + mAccess_Token; // mAccess_Token holds the access_token for the session
    request.setRawHeader("Content-Type","Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=bound1");
    request.setRawHeader("Authorization", AccessTokenBearer.toUtf8());

    // Get Reply and connect it to set Value
    QNetworkReply *reply = mQNAM.post(request, multiPart); // mQNAM is QNetworkAccessManager
    QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(uploadProgress(qint64,qint64)),
                     this, SIGNAL(setValue(qint64,qint64))); // Update in gui

    // Set timeout mechanism while waiting for reply finished
    bool stop = false;
    QTimer timer;
    timer.setSingleShot(true);
    QObject::connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::uploadProgress, [&](){
        timer.stop();
        timer.start(TIMEOUT); // Restart timer every time upload progress
    });
    QObject::connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, [&](){
        stop = true;
    });
    timer.start(TIMEOUT);

    // Wait till the response is completed
    while(!reply->isFinished()){
        QCoreApplication::processEvents();
        if(stop){
            reply->abort();
        }
    }

    // Check reply
    if(reply->error() != QNetworkReply::NoError){
        if(reply->error() == QNetworkReply::OperationCanceledError){
            emit setMessage("Error: Timeout");
        }
        else{
            emit setMessage("Error: "+reply->errorString());
        }
        delete reply;
        return false;
    }
    else{
        QByteArray rawData = reply->readAll();
        qDebug()<<"Size of reply "<<rawData.size();
        qDebug()<<"Data "<<rawData;
        delete reply;
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Edit 1**
Body.utf8 log -> "{\n\"name\": \"db_06_08_2018_16_18_11_979.sqlite\"\n}"

Comment: can you log the value of `Body.toUtf8()` and paste the output into your question

Comment: @pinoyyid Please check my edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the mistake. It was nothing but a typo in preparing the request
Before:

```
 request.setRawHeader("Content-Type","Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=bound1");
```

After:

```
 request.setRawHeader("Content-Type","multipart/related; boundary=bound1");
```

This solved the issue.